# Processing stream from a topic into the same topic (circular processing)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm having problems processing a stream from a topic into the same topic (called 'restaurant').

All seems to be working fine if I produce to a different topic. But if I produce to 'restaurant' topic the events do not seem to be registered.
Also I can peek the stream and in all cases I can see the correct events in the stream.

The restaurant stream has events (orders). The processor enriches them and sends them back to restaurant under the name 'enrichedOrder'.

```java
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

KStream<String, Event>[] source = builder.stream("restaurant",consumed)
  .branch(
    (key, value) -> value.name.equals("order"), 
    (key, value) -> true
  );

  source[0].mapValues( (value)->{value.name="enrichedOrder"; return value;} )
    .to("restaurant");
```

Restaurant topic to have 'enrichedOrder' events.

Is this possible at all?

I'm using Confluent cloud platform with kafka-streams API 2.3.

Comment: Are you sure, you have checked content properly? It should work. If you are using kafka-console-consumer please use `--from-beginning` option.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that all work fine in the actual code. But the Confluent web interface was not displaying these new events for some reason. (I was using Confluent web interface to monitor the topic)

Comment: You might want to delete this question, or put your findings as an actual answer and accept your own answer to mark the question as "resolved".

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that all work fine in the actual code. But the Confluent web interface was not displaying these new events for some reason. (I was using Confluent web interface to monitor the topic).

Comment: Also, to re-processed these events I had to use .through() before